# Reduce function not running properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, reduce

const ExpensesSummary = ({periodName, data}) => {
const expensesSum = data.reduce(function (initial, curr) { return initial + curr.amount}, 0);
console.log(data);

//here data is the dummy data in which I am having amount of the expenses

below is the dummy data

```
const Data = [
  {
    id: 'e1',
    description: 'A pair of shoes',
    amount: '99',
    date: new Date('2021-12-19'),
  },
  {
    id: 'e2',
    description: 'A pair of trousers',
    amount: '89',
    date: new Date('2022-01-05'),
  },
  {
    id: 'e3',
    description: 'Some bananas',
    amount: '5',
    date: new Date('2021-12-01'),
  },
  {
    id: 'e4',
    description: 'Book',
    amount: '14',
    date: new Date('2022-02-19'),
  },
  {
    id: 'e5',
    description: 'Another Book',
    amount: '18',
    date: new Date('2022-02-18'),
  },
];
```

The out put should be addition of the amount which is `99+89+5+14+18=225`
but the output which is coming is `0998951418`

Comment: why not use numbers instead of strings? otherwise use an unaray plus in fron to the value.